# Чтение com порта библиотекой serial python

Tags: python-3.x, serial

Здравствуйте, проблема следующая. 
Нужно читать что приходит в serial порт com3.
для этого через пип загрузил библиотеку serial

```
pip3 install serial
```

Скачивание и установка успешны. Затем запускаю следующий код:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
```

выдает ошибку

```
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'
```

В гугле выясняю что должно помочь замена на

```
from serial import serial
```

Заменяю

```
from serial import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
```

выдает ошибку

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'serial'
```

Дальнейшее гугление не помогло. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна библиотека [pyserial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) - Python Serial Port Extension, а не `serial` (A library for serializing python objects as JSON/YAML/XML, and deserializing JSON/YAML/XML).

```
pip3 install pyserial
```